# Calling Classes as if Functions in PHP

Tags: php

I need to call a class as if it is a function:

```
$lorem = new Lorem ;

$res = $lorem() ; // Throws error
```

How can I handle "$lorem()" request?
I examined Magic Methods, but no luck..
Some projects like NotORM works like that, but how?

Comment: What `$lorem()` suppose to do?

Comment: How is `Lorem` defined?  What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Probably an error exists in the Lorem class

Comment: You can use magic methods to do that, if you really want to. `__invoke()` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: You are looking for the (very rarely used) `__invoke()` magic method: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke

Comment: Lorem is just a something like StdClass, "__call" only works for "ipsum" when you try to "$lorem->ipsum()"...

Comment: Why there are always someone who so eager to close questions?? OCDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the __invoke() magic method to determine the actions of a class when used as a function, or to make the class callable.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke

Comment: Thank you, thats what I am looking for!